# Configurar directorio raiz de acceso FTP debian

Tags: servidor, debian, ftp

Hola configure un servidor web y un servidor FTP (proFTPd) en debían, hasta ahora todo esta ok pero me falta conseguir que al conectarme mediante un cliente FTP este me muestre automáticamente un directorio concreto.

eh leido que para lograr esto es necesario modificar el archivo proftpd.conf específicamente el apartado DefaultRoot el cual e probado con distintas rutas:

```
 DefaultRoot            ~/var/www/html

 DefaultRoot            /var/www/html

 DefaultRoot            var/www/html
```

ninguna consigue el resultado esperado, mediante un cliente FTP (extension de ATOM) veo toda la raíz del sistema al iniciar sesión, mediante `http://www.net2ftp.com` veo mi carpeta de usuario al iniciar sesión (root /home /username), debido a esto cree una carpeta de prueba en root /home /username / test y modifique nuevamente el archivo de configuración, sin obtener resultados.

```
 DefaultRoot            /test
```

El acceso es mediante un usuario que cree sin permisos de administración, actualmente puedo modificar y subir archivos en la carpeta que necesito pero mi problema es, como mencione al principio, que al iniciar sesión me muestre la carpeta correspondiente.